# What will GroupBy in LINQ do if it has two parameters?

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine

I am trying to understand the code below:

```cs
Color32[] colors = mesh.colors32;
IEnumerable<IGrouping<byte, int>> hierarchyMap = colors.Select((color, index) => new { color, index }).GroupBy(c => c.color.g, c => c.index);
```

I used google and only found some tutorials for GroupBy(xxx)(only one parameter inside brackets), which means xxx is the key for the group. What if there were two parameters inside the brackets?

Comment: First is key selector (by which the set will be grouped) and the second is element selector (how resulting set should be constructed). Here is the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, the accepted answer is trying to group by using two keys. It doesn't explain what if there are two parameters inside the `GroupBy` bracket.

If there are two parameters inside the bracket, it will group the elements of a sequence according to a specified key selector function and projects the elements for each group by using a specified function.

Let say we have an `Employee` class

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

And then the code logic is below.

```
var employees = new List<Employee>
{ 
    new Employee { Name="Dave", Age=25 },
    new Employee { Name="John", Age=23 },
    new Employee { Name="Michael", Age=30 },
    new Employee { Name="Bobby", Age=30 }, 
    new Employee { Name="Tom", Age=25 }, 
    new Employee { Name="Jane", Age=21 }
};

var query = employees.GroupBy(employee => employee.Age, employee => employee.Name);

foreach (IGrouping<int, string> employeeGroup in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(employeeGroup.Key);
    foreach (string name in employeeGroup)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"=> {name}");
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
25
=> Dave
=> Tom
23
=> John
30
=> Michael
=> Bobby
21
=> Jane
```

Reference from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__)

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

When using two parameters in the GroupBy method, the two parameters represents,

> **keySelector**     `Func<TSource,TKey>`
>
> A function to extract the key for each element.
>
> **elementSelector**  `Func<TSource,TElement>`
>
> A function to map each source element to an element in the
>   IGrouping.

What it does it is that it groups the sequence based on the first parameters, and projects each element of the group using the function specificied as second parameter.

Groups the elements of a sequence according to a specified key selector function and projects the elements for each group by using a specified function.

**Grouping with Two Keys**

If your intension is to group by two keys, then could use an anonymous type for grouping by multiple keys

```
.GroupBy(c => new {c.color.g, c.index})
```

For example, from the code in OP

```
 colors.Select((color, index) => new { color, index })
       .GroupBy(c => new {c.color.g, c.index});
```

Comment: Does this mean every key is a {c.color.g, c.index}?

Comment: @TIANLUNZHU That's true.

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense. The original code groups color *indices* by `color.g`. This one not only doesn't answer the original question, but shows useless grouping (the index is unique, so including it in the key basically creates one group per each item).

Comment: @IvanStoev I guess you are right. When i reread the question, my answer doesn't make sense